# Regular Expressions in Java - Checking instance variables start with a capital letter?

Tags: java, regex, expression, capitalization

How am I able to check if both the countryName and capitalName instance variables start with a capital letter?  I'm sure I have to use regular expressions involving somthing like this "^[A-Z]" but am not sure how or where to put the full code.
I am a beginner at java and would appreciate any help or suggestions.

```
java.util.regex.*;

public class CountryInfo {

    private String countryName;
    private String capitalName;

    public CountryInfo (String countryName, String capitalName) {
    super();
    this.countryName=countryName;
    this.capitalName=capitalName;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public String getCapitalName() {
        return capitalName;
    }

    public void setCapitalName(String capitalName) {
        this.capitalName = capitalName;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use reflection to get the field name.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the following code

```
char c = countryName.charAt(0);
if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
     //first character is capital letter!
```

Withouth using regex, which may be complex for a beginner.

Where to put the code?
Probably in the constructor to check if it's capital letter or not, but you should explain what you need to do if it's a capital letter and what if it isn't to be sure where to put it.

Comment: thanks very much, but this is an assignment for college in which using regular expression is required

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern to check:

```
\b[A-Z]
```

I don't know what exactly your function is supposed to do when it gets a match, so I can't really tell you where to put it. The most sensible place would probably in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Regex based solution as you desired using `String#matches(String regex)`

Create a new method in the same class as:

```
public boolean isValidDate() {
    boolean valid = true;
    if (!this.capitalName.matches("^[A-Z].*$"))
       valid = false;
    else if (!this.countryName.matches("^[A-Z].*$"))
       valid = false;
    return valid;
}
```

Now after creating an instance and populating your object you can call: `isValidDate()` to know whether data is valid or not.